# How to serialize Jackson Joda Date Format?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, apache-flink

I want to serialize objects to Json inside of a flink stream processing job. Inside of a flink job all objects need to be serializable.

I'm using Jackson to serialize my objects.

```
final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
```

When I'm using this, I get the following exception:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.cfg.JacksonJodaDateFormat
```

How can I make the object mapper including the joda module serializable?

Comment: What exactly does the object that you are trying to serialize look like? It looks like it has a `JacksonJodaDateFormat` as a member variable, which is not an object that can be converted into a JSON representation. You might want to exclude that field using `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: @Jesper It's not a matter of serializing to JSON (Jackson shouldn't have a problem serializing a `JacksonJodaDateFormat` if it needed to, though that wouldn't be useful). This is Java serialization. `JacksonJodaDateFormat` is not `Serializable`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ah yes, I see. In that case CPA could ofcourse make the field `transient`, if that works for his application.

Comment: @Soitirious yes it is java serialization. Jesper the problem is, that the field is not in my code, it is in the JodaModule class. :/

Comment: Why are you serializing a `JodaModule` instance or an `ObjectMapper`? What are you doing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Because of what Fabian said in his answer. Flink serialize the function objects. And I am using the JodaModule inside of such a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flink serializes data objects with custom serializers (unknown objects are serialized with Kryo). However, function objects (i.e., objects of classes that implement the function interfaces such as `MapFunction`) are shipped to the cluster with Java serialization.

The issue here seems to be that your `ObjectMapper` class has a non serializable field. You can try to set the field to `transient` and either:

1) overwrite the Java serialization methods or
2) implement the function as a `RichFunction` and initialize the non-serializable field in the `RichFunction.open()` method which is invoked before the first record is processed.

Comment: Initializing the non-serializable object in the RichFunction.open() function worked! You can also make the object static.

Comment: Static members in functions are dangerous. They are shared by all operators on the same taskmanager. So you need to be sure that all methods are thread-safe otherwise you'll see exceptions or strange side effects.